# Setup error :Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

Below is the detailed error message. I can't proceed with installation for the last one week. I've given full  rights to registry keys that are associated to SQL Server but nothing has worked out. For the last one week no headway.

(**Edit:** Originally I posted that we were installing SQL Server version 2012 but that was a misunderstanding between me and my team. It's clear from the error messages it is a **2008 R2** version.)

The following error has occurred:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.5058.0&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%25400xBB814387
>
> summary.txt File Overall summary:   Final result:
>   User cancelled   Exit code (Decimal):           -2068380094   Exit
>   facility code:            1207   Exit error code:               1602
>   Exit message:                  User has cancelled.   Start time:
>   2014-10-22 16:42:41   End time:                      2014-10-23
>   06:26:49   Requested action:              RunRules
>
> Machine Properties:   Machine name:                  UGJIS011
>   Machine processor count:       4   OS version:
>   Windows Server 2008   OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
>   OS region:                     United States   OS language:
>   English (United States)   OS architecture:               x64   Process
>   architecture:          64 Bit   OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
>   Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   SQL Server
>   Database Services 2008 R2   ProductName:                   SQL Server
>   2008 R2   Type:                          RTM   Version:
>   10   SPLevel:                       0   Installation location:
>   C:\Users\msenfuma - admin\Desktop\SQL_2008_R2\x64\setup\
>   Installation edition:          EVAL
>
> User Input Settings:   ACTION:                        RunRules
>   CONFIGURATIONFILE:                ENU:                           True 
>   FARMACCOUNT:                      FARMADMINPORT:
>   0   FARMPASSWORD:                  *****   FEATURES:
>   HELP:                          False   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS: 
>   False   INDICATEPROGRESS:              False   INSTANCENAME:
>      PASSPHRASE:                    *****   QUIET:
>   False   QUIETSIMPLE:                   False   RULES:
>   GLOBALRULES,SqlUnsupportedProductBlocker,PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck,Bids2008InstalledCheck,BlockInstallSxS,AclPermissionsFacet,FacetDomainControllerCheck,SSMS_IsInternetConnected,FacetWOW64PlatformCheck,FacetPowerShellCheck
>   UIMODE:                        Normal   X86:
>   False
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141022_164238\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> There are no scenario-specific rules.
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20141022_164238\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
>
> Exception summary: The following is an exception stack listing the
>   exceptions in outermost to innermost order Inner exceptions are being
>   indented
>
> Exception type:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CancelException
>       Message: 
>           User has cancelled.
>       Stack: 
>           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.UIExtension.Request.Wait()
>           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.UIExtension.UserInterfaceProxy.NavigateToWaypoint(String
>   moniker)
>           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.UIExtension.WaypointAction.ExecuteAction(String
>   actionId)
>           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String
>   actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
>           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter
>   statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun)

Comment: [View and Read SQL Server Setup Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx)

Comment: Start time: `2014-10-22 16:42:41` End time: `2014-10-23 06:26:49` did your SQL Server installation actually reached to installation page or just failed at Configuration check. Did you made sure you meet [Hardware and Software requirements][1] specially the .Net framework. Can you also add contents of file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141022_164238\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm Just paste the complete screenshot.

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.110%29.aspxUnfortunately I cannot find anything concrete

Comment: I would also like to see the output of  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141022_164238\ConfigurationFile.ini. It would be better if you can upload these logs on shared drive and share the link here

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1z0GByL  i'v

Comment: Hi Shanky thanks for the help so far. I've uploaded log files and screen shots in the above link.

Comment: @Michael: Did the answer helped, I asked for another log file to actually tell you which Reg key SQL installation is trying to change ?

Comment: @jack Douglas there is no point in putting question as off topic this is totally incorrect this is not a off topic question user had issue about installation failure he provided dumps and other information what is point in putting off topic

Comment: @Shanky my reason is this: "you are actually installing SQL Server 2008 R2 but in your question you have clearly in Bold written SQL Server 2012" - that makes it too localized I think, but lets discuss in [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap-consultancy-)

Comment: @Michael Can you please edit your question making it clear that installation was for SQL Server 2008 R2 not for 2012. Also can you please change tags to 2008 r2. If you would not change it thread will be on hold and might eventually be deleted. SO I request you to correct your Q so that others can take help of it when required.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548757/attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation-when-executing-sql-server-2019-se

Answer (score 4):

First you did a bit of mistake you are actually installing SQL Server 2008 R2 but in your question you have clearly in Bold written SQL Server 2012. Since you provided me 2008 r2 setup logs I would assume you did typo and you are installing SQL Server 2008 R2 so Please correct the question

I found below in SystemconfigurationCheck_report.htm

> Checks if the SQL Server registry keys are consistent.
>           Failed
>           The SQL Server registry keys from a prior installation cannot be modified. To continue, see SQL Server Setup documentation about how to fix registry keys.

Plus below error

[image]

As you already wrote in your question that you fiddled with registry and in this process you made registry inconsistent so SQL Server is not able to proceed with installation of Setup files its failing at setup support file installation like below

[image]

Now this means that registry is inconsistent and ACL checks cannot be performed. In that case we have to manually provide access.

1. Located HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server in registry
2. Right click and go to Permission
3. Click on Advance
4. Tick on both check box (I. Inherit from parent the permission... II. Replace permission   entries on all child objects...), click OK
5. Click OK again

Hopefully this might solve your issue. if not there is log file called as `Detail Global rules.txt` that would have information about what registry key SQL Server was trying to access it would be better if you also upload that in shared drive.

Do you have visual Studio installed on the same server please tell me ?

**Don't play with windows registry unless you are very much confident what you are doing.** I dont think This [Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799534) is applicable to your scenario but you must have a look at this

Comment: Thanks Shanky, I've looked into your Solution and am looking at refreshing. I've realized registry keys are a pain. I've done a fresh installation in a test environment having got your advice. While away my colleagues could have installed SQL server 2008 without my knowledge and it brought the inconsistent state.

Comment: Of course if you format the system and start fresh installation you would succeed I just wanted your feedback. Anyways thanks for the information :)