# Setup error :Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation

Installation of SQL Server 2014 on Windows 10 Home.

From the log details:- It seems modifying this registry key is causing the problem

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE@SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FltMgr
> ```

```
    5:02 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:     Message: 
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:         Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:     HResult : 0x84bb0001
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:         FacilityCode : 1211 (4bb)
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:         ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:     Data: 
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:       WatsonData = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE@SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FltMgr
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:       DisableRetry = true
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:     Inner exception type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:         Message: 
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:                 Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:         HResult : 0x80070005
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:         Stack: 
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String subkey, RegistryAccess requestedAccess)
(01) 2017-05-19 12:15:02 Slp: ----------------------------------------
```

I know about this thread [Setup error :Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83681/setup-error-attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation)

I did the same :- Tried changing the registry setting to full control for everyone via safe mode. Disabled defender, antivirus and firewall. But no luck.

Seems something to do with FILESTREAM in SQL server. Any idea on how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: This might actually not be a permission issue but may be because of some inaccurate values in Reg keys and that can be because of either multiple failed installations or remnants of previous failed installation. Can you upload details file on shared location for analysis and post link here

Comment: https://ufile.io/x8ro4 contains details.txt

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548757/attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation-when-executing-sql-server-2019-se

Answer (score 1):

In my Case, creating an Administrator Windows Account and installing SQL Server worked!
Also you can simply activate the built-in windows Administrator Account by running the `net user administrator /active:yes` command in command prompt(Admin Mode), then log in as Administrator. Now You can Install SQL Server without problem.

Afterwards you can use SQL Server from your own normal windows account after installation.

I would recommend deactivating Administrator account by running `net user administrator /active:no` command in command prompt(Admin Mode)